# Joining two tables with sometimes missing join values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables to join with two columns to join them on like `person_id`, `component`. For one person there can be multiple components, but the components can be the same for different person.

The problem is that one of the tables has all the correct data but the other has some missing values on the second column.

The two tables look something like this:

First table:

```
+----------+-----------+
| person_id|  component| 
+----------+-----------+
| sth      |   A       |  <-- 
| sth      |   B       |  <-- two components for sth
| sth1     |   A       |  <-- A component for sth1
| sth2     |   A       | 
| sth3     |   B       |  <-- B component for sth3 
+----------+-----------+
```

Notice that there is only one component for both sth1 and 3

Second table:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+
| person_id|  component| value |
+----------+-----------+-------+
| sth      |   A       | 1     |
| sth      |   B       | 21    |
| sth1     |   null    | 313   |<--should be matched with A component from sth1
| sth2     |   A       | 2     |
| sth3     |   null    | 12    |<--should be matched with B component from sth3
+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Notice that these null values can only be matched to a single row of table A.

So I need the values from the second table but i also need the first to match the null components to actual components. As you can see the missing component is not always the same.

If the second table has a missing component for person_id `sth1` then the first table will only have ONE component for that id
so it doesn't need to choose somehow just simply say if table B has a missing value at the component then it should be matched with table A's person id.

And of course I can't simply match person id-s because it won't know which value matches which component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below -

```
select a.person_id,a.component,value
from first_table  a
inner join second_Table b on a.person_id=b.person_id and a.component=b.component
union 
select a.person_id,a.component,value
from first_table  a
inner join second_Table b on a.person_id=b.person_id
where b.component is null
```

Answer (score 0):

First You can try joining person id and component then union the output of joining by person id when the component is Null

```
Select a.person_id,a.component,b.value 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
on a.person_id=b.person_id and a.component=b.component

UNION ALL

Select a.person_id,a.component,b.value 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
on a.person_id=b.person_id 
WHERE component is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a problem where you are using `null` for a default.  If so, I usually handle this with `left join`s:

```
select t1.person_id, t1.component,
       coalesce(t2.value, t2default.value) as value
from first_table t1 left join
     second_Table t2
     on t1.person_id = t2.person_id and t1.component = t2.component left join
     secondtable t2default
     on t1.person_id = t2.person_id and
        t2.component is null;
```

This has two advantages over `union`.  First, it does not require removal of duplicate values.  Second, this logic ensures that all rows in the first table are in the result set.